# change ruby install path windows

Tags: ruby, windows

Ruby is installed on windows at c:\Program files\ruby. Since this has a space gems fail. So i set up a shortcut at c:\ruby and change computer>>envirment variable>>path to reflect this

But ruby gems still seams to use old path. Why is this so  and how do i change it.

Comment: When you say shortcut, what do you mean? symlink, junction?

Comment: ys.. a simlink... on win it's called a shortvut

Comment: Symlinks are different than shortcuts even on Windows. =)

Comment: could you enlighten me the diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that i was trying to run ruby gem inside bash(git). The bash shell cant run ruby files/gem in windows as bash shell doesn't accept space in path or windows style url.

So use `command prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a gem on Windows a Batch file(`.bat`) that calls the ruby gem script is created. The path to the ruby script is expanded and hard coded into that Batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/Users/Justin/ruby/bin/bundle" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

Reinstalling the gems if the symlink is first in the `Path` variable would probably fix it.